# Reverse order of given numbers in python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to reverse order of given numbers in python.The [problem](http://www.spoj.pl/SHORTEN/problems/REVORDER/) says that the first line of the standard input contains one integer t (t<1001) which is the number of numbers.In each of the next t lines there is one integer n (n<1001).

Now I am trying to solve this using recursion trick:

```
def f(n,a):
   if n > 0:
      a = input()
      f(n-1,a)
   print a    
f(input(),0)
```

But this is not working properly since the last number is output twice.How to fix this ?

My obvious solution for this is:

```
n=input()
a=[1]*n
for i in range(n):a[i]=input()
a=a[::-1]
for i in range(n):print a[i]
```

If anybody is aware of any other smart solution for the same please enlighten me too.
Thanks

Comment: is this homework? just asking because you say its from a "problem."

Comment: @SB: Nobody reverses numbers using recursion except as homework...

Comment: @:Glenn Maynard:I am not sure if you are following me or not,I am just trying to use various tricks for a same problem in order to achieve a smart/shorten solution,and about the recursion thing sure you are entitled to have your opinion :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to print in the '**n == 0**' case.
Try indenting the '**print**' inside the '**if**'.

I imagine your '**a**' variable is getting re-used in the '**n == 0**' case, causing your problem.

<strike>Also, is there a particular reason you don't just read the input into an list, then reverse that list?</strike> [*I see you know how to do that from your edit*] If this is just to experiment, then more power to you. Lists in python have a **reverse()** function, though (:

FWIW, here's a slight variation on your solution I tried out:

```
def f(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    a = input()
    f(n-1)
    print a

f(input())
```

Also, there's a fun function in Python called **reversed()**, which returns an iterator.

```
x = [1,2,3]
for i in reversed(x):
    print i    # prints 3, 2, 1
```

And lastly, not exactly related, but since you seem to be learning recursion... A handy way to debug your problem  might be to put this as the first line of your f() function:

```
print '>' * n, n, a
```

Maybe then it will be clearer why you have the double-print problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution:

```
def f(n,a=None):
    if n > 0:
        f(n-1, input())
    if a is not None:
        print a

f(input())
```

It bugs me a little bit that I had to use the check on `a`, but then I realized this question is a bit artificial anyway. You don't need to know the number of items in the list in order to reverse it. Of course the `None` is in case `0` appears in the inputs.

Demo:

```
$ <<< '5
7
4
1
0
8' python Desktop/foo.py 
8
0
1
4
7
```